# Writing top 10 scores to file

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a blackjack program and would like to be able to write the top scores to a file. Obviously the first few times the program is run it will populate the high score list with every score, after which I'd like only scores that are greater than the number 10 score to be added, and the initial number 10 score (now number 11) to be deleted. I've been thinking of using a linked list like this:

```
struct highScore
{
    char name;
    int score;
    highScore *next;
};
```

My knowledge of linked lists is pretty basic so I intend on doing my research before I can actually code it.
I'm wondering if I'm overcomplicating this and if there's a simpler way to get the job done, or am I on the right track here?

Comment: Nope, it's just for me. I'm only started programming 2 months ago so forgive me if it looks that way. I'm not looking for code or anything, just a pointer on the right track

Comment: If you want to start practicing on linked-list, this is a good beginner exercise. note: in c `highScore` isn't valid, you need `struct highScore`

Comment: Sounds like you only need a limited number of places, in which case a simple 10-item array would be sufficient.

Comment: Or if you just want to get the job done, don't implement your linked list. There are so many bugs you can introduce trying to implement your own linked list. You can use the linked list in the C++ standard library. You can still code the rest in C.

Comment: No, i disagree. If you code in C dont put C++ library into it. C is C, C++ is C++, dont mix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that linked list is best approach. Do not take me wrong, but linked list is used to add and to remove at random position, most commonly at beginning or end. Problem whit linked list is that it has same inefficiency to find element as ordinary array, becuase it has to check each element until it finds one.

I think that using array will make your program having same efficiency and less complicated code.

Comparing both data structures (linked list and array):

1. Finding element is in both case proportional to length in average.
2. Inserting element at end is constant in both structures.
3. Linked lists are efficient to add element at any position, but position has to be found, so this compensates whit problem that array has, where you have to move right elements by one position on right.

I think that something like

```
  typedef struct
  {
      int score;
      char name[51]; //name should hold 50 chars and null
  } highScore;

  highScore scores[10]; // voilla 10 scores


  //or if you need little bit of complications 
  //and more speed when moving array during insertion
  highScore * scorespointer[10]; //array of 10 pointers on score
```

Will make simple solution whit same efficiency as linked list.

If you implement your structure as linked list you will not be able to serialize this directly in file, because you can store only name and score, but not pointer on next highScore. Pointers can not be stored in file, because they are dynamical allocated and are valid only during program lifetime.

If you are disappointed whit this solution, you can check [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) and [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29)  for ultimate efficency for more than few (like in your case) scores.

Comment: -1 You have to traverse the array to find the location to insert at anyway, if it's a high score list. LinkedList > Array for sure. Both require traversal, Array also requires shift, LinkedList does not.

Comment: This brings same complexity in both cases. If you have array of pointers then inserting element will be faster for array, since memmove() is freaking fast and traversing array is also faster than traversing linked list.

Comment: @SamDeHaan I have now actualy tested this. So i write code in c++ and i have used two data structures. List and vectors. It seems that vectors runs at approx 3 times faster than list. http://pastebin.com/2WFX58rA

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach looks good. Using a linked list for this makes sense, or even a queue (which can be implemented using a linked list).

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is certainly a good way to do this. It keeps the data related to a score together and with some basic bookkeeping you can keep it up to date. When you keep it sorted, you can easily insert new scores at the right place and remove too low scores from the linked list.

An alternative is to maintain two arrays with 10 elements each, one for the names and one for the scores but this has several drawbacks:

1. If you're going to add more information later, you'll need another array and more importantly,
2. Any operation that you do on one array also needs to be done on the other which can cause trouble later on (bugs).

So, in short, your solution looks good.

Comment: You can just use an array of highscore records instead of two different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand your requirement:

- the program runs and a score is obtained
- you read the scores file into a list and check the new score against the old top scores
- you modify the list and write it back to the file
- program exits.

If this is correct, then a linked list seems like overkill.  An array would do the job fine. Read each entry from the file into the array, inserting the new score as you go.  You could forego the array altogether and just write out to a file each score you read in, again inserting the new score as you go. Then rename the files (scores.txt becomes scores.bak, scores.new becomes scores.txt) - this way you get a backup of the scores file too.  Note that your file is best written as text (ie. not binary).

As has been stated, your structure will not compile as pure C code.  If you want to write in C as opposed to C++, you should make your compiler reject C++.  How you do that depends upon your platform, but it might just be a matter of naming the file scores.c instead of scores.cpp.